# Javascript Form Validation Not Successful

Tags: javascript, forms

Practicing my Javascript on a simple HTML form. Enter password in one box, enter again to confirm in the second. Password should contain 6 character (including 1 number), and no spaces. An alert message should pop up if the passwords meet the criteria and match.

I have it mostly there, in that the error messages pop up if the criteria aren't met, but I can't get to alert "Success!"  I've toyed with the if statements so many ways, I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any suggestions?

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {                

            document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', validateInput);
        }

        var userPass = document.getElementById('password').value;
        var confirmPass = document.getElementById('confirm_password').value;

        function validatePassword() {
            var userPass = document.getElementById('password').value;

            if (userPass.length == 0) { // Nothing was entered
                document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = 'Please enter a password';
            } else if (userPass.length < 6) { // Less than 6 chars 
                document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters in length'; 
            } else if (userPass.match(/\s/)) { // contains a space
                document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = 'Your password cannot contain spaces';
            } else if (!userPass.match(/\d/)) { // Does not contain a number
                document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = 'Your password must contain a number';
            } else if (userPass !== confirmPass) {
                document.getElementById('confirm_error').innerHTML = 'Passwords do not match. Please check again.';             
            } else {
                document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById('confirm_error').innerHTML = "";
                alert("Success!");  
                clearFields();
            }
        }

        function validateConfirm() {

            function clearFields (){
                document.getElementById('password').value=null;
                document.getElementById('confirm_password').value=null;
            }

            if (confirmPass.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById('confirm_error').innerHTML = "Please confirm password to proceed";
            } else if (confirmPass.length < 6) {
                document.getElementById('confirm_error').innerHTML = "Your password must be at least 6 characters in length";
            } else if (userPass !== confirmPass) {
                document.getElementById('confirm_error').innerHTML = 'Passwords do not match. Please check again.';     
            } else {
                document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById('confirm_error').innerHTML = "";
                alert("Success!");  
                clearFields();
            }              
        }  


        function validateInput() {
            validatePassword();
            validateConfirm();
        }
```

The form:

```
   <form>
   <fieldset>
        <legend>CONFIRM PASSWORD</legend>
        <label for="name">Password: </label>
        <input type="text" id="password" size="10" />
        <p id="password_error" class="error"></p>
        <label for="name">Confirm Password: </label>
        <input type="text" id="confirm_password" size="10" />
        <p id="confirm_error" class="error"></p>
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: There is no clearFields within the scope of `validatePassword`, so that should be a problem

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues

1. The function `clearFields()` is available only inside `validateConfirm`
2. You are reading the value of the confirm input only once at the page load, you need to read the new value within the validate method else it will always be empty string
3. Since you are validating the policy in the password field, not need to check it again for the confirm field since you are checking whether the confirm and password fields are the same

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', validateInput);
}


function validatePassword() {
  var userPass = document.getElementById('password').value;
  var confirmPass = document.getElementById('confirm_password').value;

  if (userPass.length == 0) { // Nothing was entered
    document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = 'Please enter a password';
  } else if (userPass.length < 6) { // Less than 6 chars 
    document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters in length';
  } else if (userPass.match(/\s/)) { // contains a space
    document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = 'Your password cannot contain spaces';
  } else if (!userPass.match(/\d/)) { // Does not contain a number
    document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = 'Your password must contain a number';
  } else if (userPass !== confirmPass) {
    document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('confirm_error').innerHTML = 'Passwords do not match. Please check again.';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('confirm_error').innerHTML = "";
    alert("Success!");
    clearFields();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function clearFields() {
  document.getElementById('password').value = '';
  document.getElementById('confirm_password').value = '';
}


function validateInput() {
  return validatePassword();
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>CONFIRM PASSWORD</legend>
  <label for="name">Password:</label>
  <input type="text" id="password" size="10" />
  <p id="password_error" class="error"></p>
  <label for="name">Confirm Password:</label>
  <input type="text" id="confirm_password" size="10" />
  <p id="confirm_error" class="error"></p>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense and helps in getting the "Success" message to alert.  However this also breaks the error messages... if they don't match or don't meet the criteria, the error messages show for a brief second and disappear. I may be able to catch this though...

Answer (score 0):

I've found two fault in your code

1. Set clearFields() function outside function    validatePassword();
2. var confirmPass enter inside function or pass from calling function

```js
window.onload = function () {

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', validateInput);
}

function validatePassword() {
    var userPass = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var confirmPass = document.getElementById('confirm_password').value;
    if (userPass.length == 0) { // Nothing was entered
        document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = 'Please enter a password';
    } else if (userPass.length < 6) { // Less than 6 chars 
        document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters in length';
    } else if (userPass.match(/\s/)) { // contains a space
        document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = 'Your password cannot contain spaces';
    } else if (!userPass.match(/\d/)) { // Does not contain a number
        document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = 'Your password must contain a number';
    } else if (userPass !== confirmPass) {
        document.getElementById('confirm_error').innerHTML = 'Passwords do not match. Please check again.';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('confirm_error').innerHTML = "";
        alert("Success!");
        clearFields();
    }
}
function clearFields() {
    document.getElementById('password').value = null;
    document.getElementById('confirm_password').value = null;
}
function validateConfirm() {
    var userPass = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var confirmPass = document.getElementById('confirm_password').value;
    if (confirmPass.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('confirm_error').innerHTML = "Please confirm password to proceed";
    } else if (confirmPass.length < 6) {
        document.getElementById('confirm_error').innerHTML = "Your password must be at least 6 characters in length";
    } else if (userPass !== confirmPass) {
        document.getElementById('confirm_error').innerHTML = 'Passwords do not match. Please check again.';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('confirm_error').innerHTML = "";
        alert("Success!");
        clearFields();
    }
}

function validateInput() {
    validatePassword();
    validateConfirm();
}
```

```html
 <form>
   <fieldset>
        <legend>CONFIRM PASSWORD</legend>
        <label for="name">Password: </label>
        <input type="text" id="password" size="10" />
        <p id="password_error" class="error"></p>
        <label for="name">Confirm Password: </label>
        <input type="text" id="confirm_password" size="10" />
        <p id="confirm_error" class="error"></p>
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```